# Unable to submit form in jquery ajax callback function

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms, submit

I am trying to submit a form after validating captcha  using an ajax request - if captcha is validated successfully , i have to submit the form.

here is the form :

```
<form action="Feedback" method="post" name="contact_us" id="contact_us_form">
     <table id="contact_us_table" style="font-family: 'Muli', serif;font-weight:bold;margin-left: 26px;margin-top: 39px;">

     <tr>
     <td> </td>
     <td height="20px" style="color: red;font-size: 12px;" id="msg">  </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
     <td><span style="color: red">*</span>Name  </td>
     <td> <input type="text" name="name" id="name" /> </td>
     </tr>

     <tr>
     <td><span style="color: red">*</span>Email  </td>
     <td> <input type="text" name="email" id="email" /> </td>
     </tr>


     <tr>
     <td width="100px;"><span style="color: red">*</span>Message  </td>
     <td> <textarea style="max-width:420px;width: 420px; height: 100;" name="message" id="message"></textarea></td>
     </tr>

     <tr>
     <td height="50px;"></td>
     <td>Human Verification.</td>
     </tr>




     <tr>
     <td><img src="<%=GlobalData.SERVER_ROOT+"simpleCaptcha.png"%>"></td>
     <td height="20px;"><input type='text' name='answer' id="answer" value=''> </td>
     </tr>

     <tr>
     <td></td>
     <td> <button class="button1" id="submit">Submit</button> </td>
     </tr>


     </table>
     </form>
```

and here is the javascript :

```
 $("#contact_us_form").submit(function(e){
             e.preventDefault();
            var email = $("#email").val(); 
            var name = $("#name").val(); 
            var message = $("#message").val();
            var answer = $("#answer").val();



            if(name == ""){
                   $("#name").focus();
                   $("#msg").html("Please enter your name");
                   return false;
                  }
            else if(email == ""){
               $("#email").focus();
               $("#msg").html("Please enter an email");
               return false;
              }
             else if(!isValidEmailAddress(email)){
               $("#email").focus();
               $("#msg").html("Email should be like : john@example.com");
               return false;
              }
             else if(message == ""){
                 $("#message").focus();
                   $("#msg").html("Please write your message");
                   return false;
                 }
             else if(answer == ""){
                 $("#answer").focus();
                   $("#msg").html("Enter what you see in image.");
                   return false;
                 }



             $.ajax({
                 type: "POST",
                 url: "CheckCaptcha",
                 data: {answer:answer}
             }).done(function(msg) {
                // alert(msg);

                 if(msg == "true"){
                    //$('#contact_us_form').submit();
                    //$('#contact_us_form').submit(); 
                       $("#contact_us_form").unbind('submit').submit();
                     //setTimeout(document.getElementById('contact_us_form').submit(), 10);
                 }
                 else{
                     $("#answer").focus();
                       $("#msg").html("Captcha Incorrect");
                       return false;
                     }
                 }).error(function(){

                 });



            });
```

You can see in javascript :

```
if(msg == "true"){

                    //$('#contact_us_form').submit(); 
                       $("#contact_us_form").unbind('submit').submit();
                     //setTimeout(document.getElementById('contact_us_form').submit(), 10);
                 }
```

i have tried all i can . but it didn't work.

is their anything wrong ?

**EDIT ::**

**This code works if i click submit two times..**

Comment: "I have tried all I can..." Please elaborate!

Comment: you can see commented code in javascript..... i have tried all of them..

Comment: Have you tried increasing the number within your TimeOut?

Comment: yes i tried it with 1000 ms but didn't work.

Comment: Personally, I would have it so PHP takes care of all your validation and Capcha and then get jQuery to return whatever error it has.  If you have multiple errors, display them using an array.  If everything is okay, send the form via PHP and return a success message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just because of this :

```
<button class="button1" id="submit">Submit</button>
```

NEVER USE 'type' as a name or id

i was using `submit` as an id. that is why the code was not working..

when i changed it to

```
<button class="button1" id="submit_button">Submit</button>
```

it worked !

Answer (score 0):

try unbind without parameters:

```
 $("#contact_us_form").unbind().submit();
```