# approach for displaying message after form submit

Tags: java, javascript, html, jakarta-ee

I have a form containing name,email,message and captcha fields.

I can submit the form and can verify the captcha  at server side, In case everything is OK i have to display a jsp using requestDispatcher. Everything works fine if captcha is correct but if it is incorrect i am redirecting user onto the same page where the form is displayed so that user can reenter the captcha. But the main problem with this approach is the form get's cleared, that means user have to refill the whole thing again. 
How can i avoid this thing so that user don't require to refill the form.

And is their any other better approach for this.

Iv'e already tried making an ajax call to validate captcha but have got some problem with that approach. [Unable to submit form in jquery ajax callback function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11673848/1485216)

Comment: can you post you JQuery ajax submit code?

Comment: i have given a link in my question...... you can find code there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this, call click event on some div say 'submit', then call ajax call and get the result. Depending upon result you can decide whether to submit the form or not.

submit is DIV
printCoupon is form

```
$("#submit").click(function(){

        var response = '';
        $.ajax({ type: "GET",   
                 url: "ajaxprintcoupon",   
                 async: false,
                 success : function(text)
                 {
                     response = text;
                 }
        });

        alert(response);

        if(response == 'Testing'){
            $('#printCoupon').submit();
        }else{
            // no change
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [XmlHTTPRequest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest) in the JS code.

You assign callbacks for getting the answer and handle it as you wish. In my case I was getting from the server the code to be output, the Form with ALL INPUTS remained in the previous condition, and the only div 'output' at html page was modified.

Here is a short example of my program:
html of the page

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/script.js">/script>
<form name="someForm">
<p><b>Enter your text here:</b></p>`

<p><textarea rows="10" cols="45" name="code"></textarea></p>
<input type="button" value="Send it" onclick="sendIt()"/>
</form> </code>
<div id="output"></div>
```

in my case script.js only updates the part of the page

```
function sendIt() {
    var theCode = document.codeHolderForm.code.value;
    var linkToDiv = document.getElementById("output");
    linkToDiv.innerHTML = 'p> Server response below: p>';

    var request = getXmlHttp();

    request.open("POST", "/", true);
    request.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    request.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (request.readyState != 4) return;

        if (request.status == 200) {
            linkToDiv.innerHTML += 'p>' + request.responseText + '/p>';
        } else {
            handleError(request.statusText);
        }
    };

    request.send("code=" + theCode);

}

function handleError(message) {
    alert("Error: "+message)
}

function getXmlHttp() {
    var xmlhttp;
    try {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    } catch (e) {
        try {
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (E) {
            xmlhttp = false;
        }
    }
    if (!xmlhttp && typeof XMLHttpRequest != 'undefined') {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    return xmlhttp;
}
```